# How do you pass a string through 2 activities?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I need to send an input from a user in one activity that sends it to `activity2` and then `activity2` sends the input from `activity1` to `activity3`. visually, it would go:

`activity1` has an edit text field which sends the input to `activity2`, `activity2` uses that same input and sends it to `activity3`.

```
(activity1) --String--> (activity2) --String--> (activity3)
```

Do I have to getIntent from `activity1` and send it to `activity3` from the `onclick` method in `activity2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String passString= "information im sending";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("DataKey", passString);
startActivity(intent);

//in your second activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
String recieveString = intent.getStringExtra("DataKey");

//repeat the same in your second activity but this time the string will change
Intent intent = new Intent(this, thirdActivity.class);
intent.putExtras("DataKey", recieveString);
startActivity(intent);

//in your third activity
Intent intent = getIntent();
String recieveString2 = intent.getStringExtra("DataKey");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass it as an extra to the second activity:

```
String string  = "whatever";

Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
i.putExtra("somename", string);
startActivity(i);
```

Then get it in the second activity like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String string = intent.getExtras().getString("somename");
```

You can then repeat that process in Activity2 (with some different variable names as to not confuse yourself later) to send from the second activity and get in Activity3